# I need to execute javascript code having import statement in apache JMETER

Tags: javascript, jmeter, load, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I have to run Javascript code having ethers library required in Jmeter. I searched other blogs and it recommended me to use BSF sampler. I didn't find BSF sampler in jmeter 5.5. Please find below code.

```
const ethers = require('ethers');

const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider('API_URL');
const myPrivateKey = 'PRIVATE_KEY';
const myWallet = new ethers.Wallet(myPrivateKey, provider);
const amount = 100;

async function transferTokens(){
    const transaction = await myWallet.sendTransaction({
        to: '0x7de3280c66ecee8f4cbd8fb78850229d8f10d22f',
        value: ethers.parseEther(amount.toString()),
    });
    await transaction.wait();
}

transferTokens();
```

Earlier I tried using groovy but couldn't succeeded. I am using Jmeter 5.5 and Java 17.0.7

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you can use [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) with JavaScript language but:

1. Using JavaScript is [not recommended from performance perspective](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy), you should use Groovy
2. JavaScript engine [was removed in Java 15](https://openjdk.org/jeps/372) so you will need to either downgrade your JDK or use an alternative JVM like [GraalVM](https://www.graalvm.org/)
3. JavaScript support is limited to [ECMAScript 5.1](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/) so you won't be able to use modern features and if `ethers` library (whatever it is) is using them - your script will fail
4. `require('ethers');` directive won't work, you will need to download the module and provide the full path